# url loads differently in browser and webview

Tags: android, url, webview

I am loading a url for my app. When I load the url in a browser it loads the right content. But when I load it in a webview I get a different content.

Here is my code:-

```
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl(url);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

What can be going wrong?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? What is the html rendered in a browser and what on the webview ?

Comment: @antoniom its just a url for a login page that I want to load. I do not have access to the html code behind it